# VSCode, webpack, devServer, hot reload (HMR) and remote debugging - do I have to pick one?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webpack, vscode-debugger, webpack-hmr

I will paste what I hope are my relevant config files at the end, please let me know if I included too little (or too much, so I don't confuse future searchers). For context, I am debugging a complex, monolithic web app that runs only in tandem with a server which I'm pretty sure the details of are irrelevant. I set up a webpack devServer with HMR enabled, and a proxy for the rest of my files. For production, webpack packs my app into a single JavaScript file that we deploy.

Webpack devServer successfully compiles to memory, and when we connect, the proxy correctly pulls in all the non-webpack stuff, and when we then change code, it is recompiled on the fly and our web client updates in real time. That's fantastic, and is exactly as I wanted it!

However, as soon as I attach the VSCode debugger to our Chromium instance in order to have awesomeness like break points and variable inspections, HMR stops working. The moment I stop the debugger, HMR reloads. Connect debugger, HMR stops working again. I figured maybe the 'reload' button in the VSCode debug hover ... thingy would at least manually reload changes, but it doesn't seem to do anything when remote begging Chrome.

Is that a limitation of the technology stack I am using, or am I 'doing it wrong' ™ ?

`launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "name": "Attach to Chrome running against localhost",
            "urlFilter": "http://127.0.0.1:9000/*",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "trace": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Relevant parts of `webpack.common.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    appClient: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app-client.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/client/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [ ... ]
  },
  optimization: { ... },
  plugins: [
    ...
    new ReactRefreshPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    static: {
      directory: outputPath,
      serveIndex: true
    },
    devMiddleware: {
      index: false
    },
    proxy: [
      {
        context: ['**', '!/client/app-client.js'],
        target: 'http://localhost:8000',
        proxyTimeout: 1000 * 60 * 30,
        timeout: 1000 * 60 * 30
      },
    ],
    compress: false,
    port: 9000,
    hot: true
  }
};
```

Comment: Is it just that your Chrome browser is in paused state?.  HMR will stop if you pause Chrome.  Just a note, Chromes built in debugger is pretty descent, so what I tend to do is use VSCodes debugger for server side stuff, and just use Chrome for client side, the separation seems better that way too.

Comment: Simply attaching is enough to stop HMR, even if I have no breakpoints. I do all my development in VSCode, and I would rather not use a totally different tool with different hotkeys, different visuals, different layouts, none of my plugins or snippets or a git console, etc., unless this combination really is broken in a way that can't be fixed.

Comment: Correction to the above comment: having NO breakpoints in the entire project lets me attach without breaking HMR. But having even one, even if it isn't or can't be triggered, is enough to break HMR. Also, adding a breakpoint and removing it again will permanently land me in broken-HMR-land.

Comment: Are you sure the client is not pausing?,  developers can often put `debugger;` into code and if you attach with a debugger it will automatically pause there.  You should be able to keep clicking the play button if this is the case.

Comment: The play (well, the step into/over) button is grayed out and non-functional unless actively hitting a breakpoint.

Comment: Is there a dropdown next to the debugger pallet?.  I'm wondering if a webWorker might be pausing.